# Object creation: Pointer to dynamically allocated data inside a value type object - good or bad?

Tags: c

I have a simple struct:

```
typedef struct {
    int width, height;
    unsigned char *pixels;
} image;
```

Which one is the better API?

```
image *imagecreate(int w, int h) {
    image *img = malloc(sizeof(image));
    img->width = w;
    img->height = h;
    img->pixels = calloc(w * h, 3);
    return img;
}

void imagefree(image *img) {
    free(img->pixels);
    free(img);
}
```

or

```
image imagecreate(int w, int h) {
    image img;  
    img.width = w;
    img.height = h;
    img.pixels = calloc(w * h, 3);
    return img;
}

void imagefree(image *img) {
    free(img->pixels);
    img->width = img->height = 0;
}
```

?

It seems to be overkill to do an additional malloc() for such a small struct which is only a wrapper around a pointer to the real dynamically allocated data. But on the other hand it feels unnatural (to me) to hide a pointer to dynamically allocated memory inside a value type. One could think that you don't have to free it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're talking about API. So it's crucial that **it should be easy for your clients to use correctly and hard to use incorrectly**.

**A small improve on option #2**

For example, if I'm the user of your second API:

```
image imagecreate(int w, int h);
void imagefree(image *img);
```

I probably won't even notice the need to call `imagefree` because `imagecreate` returns an object, not a pointer to an object, while `imagefree` needs a pointer. I may think that `imagefree` is only a wrapper of `delete image` for a heap allocated object. So I won't use it for a "stack" object.

Therefore, this is better:

```
image imagecreate(int w, int h);
void imagefree(image img);
```

While you have a heap-allocated member inside `image`, but you hide it in these APIs which is good. And they have consistent "lookings" which is better, and less error-prone.

**So what about option #1?**

As to your first option, is that even better? That depends (on individuals). As to me, I perfer option #1.

```
image *imagecreate(int w, int h);
void imagefree(image *img);
```

*Why?*

Although we don't have a way to enforce the resource auto destruction by destructor like RAII in C++, usually more attention is paid for C programmers who see a "pointer" returned from an API(we are sensitive to pointers, aren't we? ;). It's much likely that they keep asking themselves: is it dynamicly allocated inside `imagecreate`? Do I need  deallocate it via some other API?

Comment: You convinced me. I'll probably go with the pointer return value version.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that your `struct` is allocated dynamically in the first case and automatically in the second. That's a matter of personal preference, coding standards and opinion. Second way seems safer to me because its one less `free` to remember to do, but since you've got to `free` anyway - doesn't really matter all that much.

Note that in the second case the `struct` is copied into the return value. You seem to be dealing with the pointer in it well, but its a potential landmine right there.

Comment: i will certainly prefer the first one, pointers are easier to manage in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

i would go with the first. assume you have a descriptor'char name[100]' in your struct, your second would use 100byte of stackspace, which must be handled by the operating system, whereas the first memory my be handled by yourself (using a selfwritten garbage collector instead of the standard malloc) and you can move the handle to the object around as you please without having to take care of your limitied stack space.

Comment: I usually manage strings as char *. But you're right, if my struct should grow in the future I would waste more stack space.